# How to set angular material tab content height sizes by content?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a page It has tabs.

My first tab has a map. And other has plain text.

```html
    <div class="container">
        <mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
            <mat-drawer-content>
                <mat-tab-group [dynamicHeight]="true">
                     <mat-tab>
                        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                            <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon" style="margin-right: 5px;">feed</mat-icon>
                            <span style="margin-right: 5px;">Tab-1</span>
                        </ng-template>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <map></map>
                        </div>
                    </mat-tab>
                    <mat-tab>
                        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                            <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon" style="margin-right: 5px;">feed</mat-icon>
                            <span style="margin-right: 5px;">Tab-2</span>
                        </ng-template>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <article></article>
                        </div>
                    </mat-tab>
                </mat-tab-group>
    
            </mat-drawer-content>
        </mat-drawer-container>
    </div>
```

So my first tab content should be fit the content (100% - tab header ) of page and do not need scroll.

And second page should have scroll if page content is long.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried **overflow: scroll; max-height: 10rem;** or something like that? If you make a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) we can more easily help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this solution but it works until I find a better one.

I've added clas `second-tab` to the content div of your second tab

```
<div class="tab-content second-tab">
```

CSS follows:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container, .mat-drawer-container, .mat-tab-group, .mat-tab-body-content, .second-tab  {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

It is important that all containers between `body` and `<div class="container">` also have `height: 100%; overflow: auto;`